# Android. onReceiveValue method is not called after WebView.evaluateJavascript execution

Tags: android, android-webview

I've created a new project based on Login Form template with Android Studio 1.5.1 and modified it little for my needs.

Here is `build.gradle` content

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mia.jsrun"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}

allprojects {
    buildDir = "/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```

and here is my test code

```
private void test() {
    Log.d(TAG, "inside test()"); // is printed
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){console.log('hello');return 'hello2'})()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            Log.e(TAG, "value received: " + s); // this is NOT printed
        }
    });
    Log.e(TAG, "after evaluateJavascript execution"); // is printed
}
```

Though I can see that `evaluateJavascript` method is invoked (logger prints before and after its execution) `onReceiveValue` is not.

What is wrong with my code or configuration?

Answer (score 5):

Answering myself.

It was enough just to call `webview.loadUrl("");` before `evaluateJavascript()` method invokation.

```
private void test() {
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("");
    webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return {foo:"bar"}})()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            Log.e(TAG, s); // {foo:"bar"}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I confirm that `loadUrl("")` is needed on KitKat devices, now would be good to know why.